# How to set up interoperability between internal Swift and Objective-C classes when developing a Framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, bridging-header

I have a **Framework** with mixed Objective-C and Swift classes and i'd like to communicate between them keeping the Swift interface internal (without making Swift classes and methods public). Is there a way to achieve that?

P.S. Please pay attention that since it's a Framework project, it's not an option to use the bridging header solution, because it's not supported for frameworks.

Comment: Please review [ask]. Best if you can show some (minimal) code that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: *without making classes public.* what is the problem with keeping the classes internal? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind can you please elaborate ... i am getting "using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported , Command CompileSwiftSources Failed

Comment: @muzzammil sorry, missed the part where you said that it's an SDK. Is your target a static library or a framework?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind: its a framework

Answer (score 2):

There is actually not that much magic around Swift and Objective-C interoperability. First, let's take a look at what [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c) says:

> When you’re building an app target, you can import your Swift code
> into any Objective-C `.m` file within that same target using this syntax
> and substituting the appropriate name:
>
> ```
> #import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
> ```
>
> By default, the generated header contains interfaces for Swift
> declarations marked with the public or open modifier. If your app
> target has an Objective-C bridging header, the generated header also
> includes interfaces marked with the internal modifier.

The automagic part merely generates Objective-C interfaces for us. Yes, the generated part for `internal` interfaces happens only if we use the bridging header and Xcode doesn't support bridging headers for framework targets. However the documentation explicitly says that internal interfaces are still accessible to Objective-C runtime (emphasis mine):

> Because the generated header is part of the framework’s public
> interface, only declarations marked with the public or open modifier
> appear in the generated header for a framework target. **Methods and
> properties that are marked with the internal modifier and declared
> within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class are accessible
> to the Objective-C runtime**. However, they’re inaccessible at compile
> time and don’t appear in the generated header for a framework target.

It means, that while *generated* headers are `public`/`open` only, nothing prevents you from writing the same interfaces *manually* and use them for internal classes.

Consider the following swift class:

```swift
@objc
class InternalClass: NSObject {
    
    @objc
    var mValue = 64
    
    @objc
    func call() {
        print("Hello from swift")
    }   
}
```

All parts of it are exposed to the Objective-C runtime *somehow*, it's just unknown how exactly. Since nobody is going to generate this guidance we can just describe it ourselves. Here is a header file `TDWInternalClass.h` which has this description:

```objc
@interface TDWInternalClass : NSObject

@property(assign, nonatomic) NSInteger mValue;

- (void)call;

@end
```

The problem here is that when Objective-C classes out of Swift interfaces are generated, their names are mangled, so `TDWInternalClass` interface would have hard time finding the `InternalClass` implementation. However it's possible to change the runtime name for the Swift declaration by providing argument to `@objc` attribute:

```swift
@objc(TDWInternalClass)
class InternalClass: NSObject
```

As we deal with a Framework target, don't forget to add this manually implemented header to the `Header` section of the `Build Phases` (I use the `Project` section to avoid exposing this header to the client code):
[image]

And we are done. The internal Swift class implementation is now accessible to project's own Objective-C classes through the `TDWInternalClass` interface, and at the same time this `InternalClass` is not accessible by the client code of the framework:

```
#import "TDWInternalClass.h"
#import "TDWClass.h"

@implementation TDWClass

- (void)printData {
    TDWInternalClass *instance = [TDWInternalClass new];
    [instance call]; // prints "Hello from swift"
    NSLog(@"%ld", instance.mValue); // prints "64"
    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution, although hacky, is that you could mark the private swift methods with an Objective-C decorator `@objc`, and then call them from Objective-C using `performSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your Objective-C headers public to use in Swift, you have to create a `module.map` file at the root of your project and add all your internal/private headers:

```
module FrameWorkProjectName_Internal {
    // import your private headers here
    export *
}
```

Then, in your `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` build settings add `$(SRCROOT)/FrameWorkProjectName` so that this module can be found by Swift classes.

To use the Objective-C code of the said module you have to import `FrameWorkProjectName_Internal` in your Swift file.

To use internal Swift classes in your Objective-C code, first you mark the classes/methods with `@objc`/`@objcMembers`. Since you don't want to make your Swift interface public you can either use [`performSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418867-performselector) to send messages OR you can manually create a header containing all your Swift interface definitions. For example, define type symbol name or selector name in your swift file with `@objc` attribute:

```swift
@objc(FrameWorkProjectName_SwiftType)
class SwiftType: NSObject {
    func call() { /* Do something */ }
}
```

and then define the swift type interface in your header file:

```objectivec
SWIFT_CLASS("FrameWorkProjectName_SwiftType")
@interface SwiftType : NSObject

- (void)call;

@end
```

When defining type symbol names make sure that it doesn't conflict with other names in your or any other external module. To avoid this try to include your framework name in symbol name.

Be advised, that `SWIFT_CLASS` macro is generated as part of `{TargetName}-Swift.h` header.

### Some Clarifications:

These are some clarification points answering some comments:

> 1. The header {FrameWorkProjectName}.h is not a bridging header, it's the umbrella header of a framework, where only public headers can be exposed, which contradicts the requirements of the question.

Yes for the framework it is called umbrella header, but you can achieve the same effect of bridging header in app targets, the only difference being the headers have to be public to be included here. And the side effect being the declarations in these headers would be exposed to consumers of your library.

While this point doesn't address your question specifically, I put it as a workaround if you think the actual action is quite cumbersome and requires a lot of manual work for your time constraints.

> For framework projects, a bridging header is just not supported, so you have to rely on swift-generated headers which only include public interfaces

Swift generated header is used to expose your Swift interfaces to Objective-C. They basically achieve the opposite of what bridging headers do. So in short,

Bridging header => Expose Objective-C declarations to Swift in app target.
Umbrella header => Expose Objective-C declarations to Swift in framework target and targets consuming the framework.
Swift generated header => Expose Swift interfaces to Objective-C (for frameworks declarations has to be public)

For more detail, you can go through official docs for [importing objective-c into swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-objective-c-into-swift) and [importing swift into objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c).

> 2. A few times you suggest to make Swift/Objective-C interface public, which is not really a solution to the question, as it looks for a way to avoid that.

These also I put as workarounds if you think the actual action is quite cumbersome and requires a lot of manual work for your time constraints.

> 3. You cannot use SWIFT_CLASS macro without importing the -Swift.h generated header. It's redundant when it comes to use of internal classes

You are correct, unfortunately, I missed that. Thanks for adding this point.

Comment: `Not sure what you mean by you can't use bridging header in framework project` in non-framework projects when a bridging header is used, all internal Swift classes are also subject for interoperability with Objective-C classes. For framework projects, a bridging header is just not supported, so you have to rely on swift-generated headers which only include public interfaces

Comment: I think your answer is the most comprehensive one so far, but it needs a few amendments: 1) The header `{FrameWorkProjectName}.h` is not a bridging header, it's the umbrella header of a framework, where only public headers can be exposed, which contradicts the requirements of the question. 2) A few times you suggest to make Swift/Objective-C interface public, which is not really a solution to the question, as it looks for a way to avoid that. 3) You cannot use `SWIFT_CLASS` macro without importing the `-Swift.h` generated header. It's redundant when it comes to use of internal classes